# Accent problem using texstudio latex

Tags: accents

What is the problem with this code?
I am working on Mac OS X.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pts,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % pour les accents
\title{Rapport d'avancement} 
\author{XYZ} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
  blalalal
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\section{État de l'art}
\section{Description du système}
\section{Algorithme}
\section{Résultats}
\section{Analyses et discussions}
\section{Conclusions et perspectives}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note also that `16pts` is not an option of the `article` class. It doesn't throw an error since it will just pass the option along to loaded packages. (In fact, the only valid sizes are `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`—but that is a different question that I've seen but have yet to find again.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Option `applemac` is the source of the problem. It seems (compiled on PC) that we can omit it. If not, follow the expalanation from the help message on error about options clash.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 16pts,notitlepage]{report}
 \usepackage{amsfonts} 
 %\usepackage{amsfonts} %double! -- PS
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
%  \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % pour les accents %% without seems to work --PS
  \title{Rapport d'avancement} 
   \author{XYZ} 
  \begin{document}

  \maketitle
  \begin{center}
    blalalal
    \end{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

%\newpage % commented only to have all on one page
      \section{État de l'art}
      \section{Description du système}
       \section{Algorithme}
       \section{Résultats}
       \section{Analyses et discussions}
       \section{Conclusions et perspectives}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, it is not the source of the error. When I omit it I obtain any thing. For exeample : État de l'art =ÃL’tat de l’art.

Comment: @phdstudent Can you then remove ` \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or give both options in one square bracket?